# Перезапуск php файла с теми же параметрами $_POST

Tags: php, post, исключения, reload

есть файл на который время от времени приходит  POST запрос и дальше он обрабатывается и некоторые данные записываются в БД. Недавно случилась такое: файл был запущен 3 раза((судя по логам)каждые 8 сек) с тем же POST, в итоге в БД 3 одинаковые записи. Что это могло быть?
Мои варианты: 
1.было 3 запроса на этот файл
2.ошибка которая привела к перезапуску файла с теми же POST параметрами

Comment: Первый вариант. Одинаковые записи в БД - проблема архитектора данных. Всегда можно добавить уникальные ключи

Comment: Очищайте $_POST сразу после отправки, с помощью locaton или другими способами делайте редиректы. action у формы не оставляйте пустым а пропишите туда отдельный скрипт для обработки $_POST затем в том отдельном скрипте выполняйте все запросы и делайте редирект обратно на форму, ну или на страничку с сообщением об успехе

Comment: @китайецИзКитая этот файл связан с другим сервисом(api), наш файл только принимает этот $_POST. Я написал проверку на случай дублирования, но его там в априори не должно было бы быть(

Comment: @Vasyl Danilyuk значит нужно решать на стороне отправки эту проблему. Если действительно одинаковые на все 100%  $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Если отправка идет из формы это банально могло быть тройное нажатие. Данные пост можно отправлять любое количество раз. А вот три записи в базе если вас смущают, то нужно по уникальным столбцам, которые не должны дублироваться поставить в базе UNIQUE и дальше ловить Exception или делать проверку на уже существующие данные в базе перед записью и записывать только  если таких данных нет. Второй вариант при запуске обработчика POST записывать в файл timestamp запуска обработчика и дальше проверять если запуск был менее 10 секунд назад то ничего не делать.